# ¿Como concatenar varios resultados de mi bd en una celda en php?

Tags: php, ajax

estoy haciendo una consulta en mi base de datos donde concateno mis rutas para mostrarlo en un solo registro desde mi vista en php, así se ve en mi bd.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quisiera saber la forma de que en la vista de mi tabla en php se vea por separado, ya que quiero dar opción a descargar cada uno, así estoy llamándolo en mi código

```
<td class="td_row_text" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="' . $value["rutaArchivoAdj"] . '" download>Download Text</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Hola para separar deberias usar explode de preferencia debes de usar alguna coma para 
separar de la cadena principal 

$pizza  = "porción1 porción2 porción3 porción4 porción5 porción6";
$porciones = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $porciones[0]; // porción1
echo $porciones[1]; // porción2

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Si lo que se ve en la imagen son varias filas, entonces en PHP recorre el conjunto de resultados fila a fila y ve construyendo los enlaces.

Comment: En si yo lo agrupo el resultado, ya que los datos son iguales, lo unico que cambia son las rutas, por eso lo concateno para ver las distintas rutas en un solo resultado, pero eso me afecta a la hora de utilizarlo en mi vista en php, y a que lo quiero colocar en una etiqueta que permita descargar el archivo de discha ruta, y ahí se une las 3 rutas, lo cual no me permite descargar nada